# Small detail problem

Tags: modeling, mesh

I am trying to model a katana: I got everything to a point where I am satisfied with it except small details on hilt, I just want those white parts to be little extruded but unsure on how to do it.

I've tried boolean modifier and knife tool but both breaks the mesh.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use separate geometry?

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more? I want to extrude it inwards, so adding a cube or something would really help me achieve that.

Comment: Sorry, I misread.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed a very complex geometry to create.

1. Create the base without the diamondshaped details as a reference.
2. Create a new mesh and enable [Snapping](https://docs.blender.org/manual/nb/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/snap.html#transform-snapping) to Surfaces.
3. Create the diamond shape from the top view. Subdivide it, add supporting edgeloops, then snap it to the reference hilt's surface.
4. Extrude the remaining loose edges guide them around to the back of the hilt. At this point, I removed three quarters of the geometry and added an XY mirror modifier.
5. Extrude the concave detail as the last step.

[image: hilt geometry]