# How to model this Shape?

Tags: modeling

I tried to model the inner half, then the outside individually, but still can't get this shape.

I only want to know about the upper half.

[image]

Comment: there are some engravings here, what level of details do you need?

Comment: Not so much but at least that will look to eye.

Comment: [Related question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/121968/30849)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a try, I've followed the profile shape, switch view, add some vertical edges, mirror, begin to draw all the holes with additional edges, extrude one time to give thickness, extrude a second time to dig the holes, put some additional edge loops to sharp the angles. At the end I've added the circle drawing with the help of the knife or knife project tools, but I could have created it earlier (on the basic plane, before the first extrude).

[image]

Comment: oh bro thank you so much